# To praise a text by saying it has nothing excessive

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

A friend of mine is a journalist, and I want to praise his new article by saying that it's not "a lot of words with a little sense", but the opposite. The ideas are solid, the wordings are precise, there are no excessive words, and there are no words or phrases that are trying to look smarter than they are. It's like an idealized Spartan warrior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Concise" and "succinct"** are both perfect for this situation.

Concise:

> giving a lot of information clearly and in a few words; brief but comprehensive. [[Lexico](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/concise)]

Succinct:

> (especially of something written or spoken) briefly and clearly expressed. [[Lexico](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/succinct)]